# XSD: One and only one element of a certain type should be declared

Tags: xml, xsd

Say that I have a `PetCage` element that should contains one and only one `AnimalElement` type like so:

```
<PetCage>
    <Cat Name="Kitty">
</PetCage>

<PetCage>
    <Dog Name="Buddy">
</PetCage>
```

Both `Cat` and `Dog` are of `AnimanlElement` type. How can I express said rule in XSD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you require is a [choice element](http://www.w3schools.com/Schema/el_choice.asp) in your schema. It'll allow you to express that only one from a set of elements may appear.

EDIT: you'll need to specify a name for the element, either directly via `name` or in reference to an element defined elsewhere via `ref`.

Your only alternative **as far as I know** is to have something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">

    <xs:element name="PetCage">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="animal" type="Animal" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:complexType name="Animal" abstract="true">
        <xs:attribute name="Name" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="Cat">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="Animal"></xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

This would validate XML files of a form like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PetCage>
    <animal xsi:type="Cat" Name="String"/>
</PetCage>
```

Unfortunately this leaves you tied to that `animal` element name. I doubt that XML Schema allows you to specify a specific type and lets you use a wildcard for the name. XML Schema validates based on element names and, if the element is defined with an abstract type, the `xsi:type` attribute. There is an `xs:any` declaration, but that can't be tied to any specific type. The following will validate as best as possible, but still allows any element defined under the schema root to be used:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">

    <xs:element name="PetCage">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:any processContents="strict" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:complexType name="Animal" abstract="true">
        <xs:attribute name="Name" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:element name="cat" />
    <xs:complexType name="Cat">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="Animal"></xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

It would validate this correctly:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PetCage>
    <cat Name="snookums"/>
</PetCage>
```

... but it wouldn't stop you from putting a PetCage in a PetCage.

I'm hoping someone with good knowledge of the XML Schema spec can confirm that this is correct or, preferably, offer the desired solution.

Comment: Correct, a choice allows me to express that only one from a set of elements may appear. But, I don't understand how I can tell the choice element to allow only one from a set of elements from the same type. <choice><element type="Animal"></choice>. An example would be great.

Answer (score 2):

```
<xs:complexType name="PetCage">
    <xs:choice>
         <xs:element name="Cat" type="AnimanlElement" />
         <xs:element name="Dog" type="AnimanlElement" />
    </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
<!-- AnimanlElement definition -->
<xs:complexType name="AnimanlElement">
    <xs:attribute name="Name" type="xs:string" />
</xs:complexType>
```

For more: http://www.w3schools.com/Schema/el_choice.asp

Comment: Would it be possible to not declare the choices explicitly and just say "I just need 1 of any AnimalElement"?

Comment: @Ian Edited my answer to clarify. I realized you were asking for something more specific than simply xs:choice right after I posted.

Comment: @NicGibson Agreed, but you'd still need to list every possible element name, right? Or are substitution groups yet something else than `xs:group`?

Comment: Something else - [W3C XSD Primer](http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xmlschema-0-20010502/#SubsGroups)